# Yet another ordered map vs. unordered (hash) map question

Tags: c++, hash, dictionary

This is a very naive question, yet I can't find an explicit discussion of it. 
Everybody agrees that using a hash for a map container with only 10 elements, is overkill.. an ordered map will be much faster. With a hundred; a thousand, etc. a map should scale  by logN where N= # of pairs in the map. So for a thousand, it takes three times as long; a million, six times as long; 10 billion, nine times as long.

Of course, we are led to believe that a well designed hashed container can be searched in O(1) (constant) time vs O(logN) for a sorted container. But what are the implied constants? At what point does the hash map lose the map in the dust? Especially, if the keys are integers, there is little overhead in the key search, so the constant in map would be small.

Nevertheless, just about EVERYBODY thinks hashed containers are faster. Lots of real time tests have been done.

What's going on?

Comment: oops, ten times as long....not that it makes much difference

Comment: You're using the wrong log -- should be base 2 rather than base 10 for a binary tree based map...

Answer (score 3):

As you've said, a hash based map does have the potential to be asymptotically faster than a binary search tree, with queries in `O(1)` vs `O(log(N))` time - but this is entirely dependent on the performance of the hash function used over the allowable distribution of input data.

There are two important worst-case situations to think about with a hash table:

1. All data items generate the same hash index, therefore all items end up in the same hash bucket - querying the hash map will take `O(N)` in this case.
2. The distribution of hash indices generated by the data is extremely sparse, therefore most hash buckets are empty. You can still end up with `O(1)` query time in this case but the space complexity can essentially become unbounded in the limit.

A binary search tree on the other hand (at least the red-black tree used in most standard library implementations) enjoys worst-case `O(log(N))` time and `O(N)` space complexity.

The up-shot of all of this (in my opinion) is that if you know enough about your input data to design a "good" hash function (doesn't have too many collisions, doesn't generate too sparse a distribution of hash buckets) using the hash map will generally be a better choice.

If you can't ensure the performance of your hash function over your expected inputs use a BST.

The exact point at which one becomes better than the other is entirely problem/machine dependent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Maybe my question was too vague, but am I right that searching a ten billion entry map (in RAM) would take 10 times as long as searching a ten entry map?

Comment: @Mike: Asymptotically, yes that's about right. The exact number of operations is implementation defined though (the big-Oh notation obviously hides any constant factors). BST's will also typically have an allowable range of "balance", so the exact number of operations done at any particular time depends on the current amount of imbalance in the tree - this constant factor gets absorbed into the `O(log(N))`...

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly noted - the devil is in the details (in this case - constants). You have to benchmark your code to decide which is more efficient for you, because the **O-Notation** is for infinitesimal values while you're dealing with the real-world constraints.

The hash would be faster if it is indeed O(1) (i.e.: the has function is really really good) and the hash function calculation is relatively fast (to begin with - doesn't depend on the size of the input).

The overhead on the map is traversing the tree and while the key comparison may be more or less fast (integers faster, strings slower), traversing the tree is always dependent on the input (the tree depth). For larger trees, consider using B-Trees instead of the standard map (which in C++ is implemented usually with red-black trees).

Again, the magic word is **benchmark**.

Answer (score 1):

The exact point where hash maps are faster will be machine-dependent.

It is true that it only takes O(log n) "steps" to traverse the map.  But looking at the constant factor for a moment, note that the base on that log is 2, not 10; and the binary tree is probably implemented as a red-black tree, which is not perfectly balanced in general.  (If memory serves, it can be up to 2x deeper than log2(n).)

However, what really drives the difference is the *poor locality* of the ordered map.  Each of those O(log n) steps involves an impossible-to-predict branch, which is bad for the instruction pipeline.  Worse, it involves chasing a random pointer to memory.  The rule of thumb on modern CPUs is: "Math is fast; memory is slow."  This is a good rule to remember because it becomes more true with every generation.  CPU core speeds generally improve faster than memory speeds.

So unless your map is small enough to fit in cache, those random pointer dereferences are *very* bad for overall performance.  Computing a hash is just math (and therefore fast), and chasing O(1) pointers is better than chasing O(log n); usually much better for large n.

But again, the exact point of hash table dominance will depend on the specific system.

Comment: `O(log10 N) = O(lg2 N)`. `log10N` and `lg2N` differ only by a *constant* factor of around 3.

Comment: @quasiverse:  Of course.  And the 2x factor for a red-black tree is also "just" a constant factor.  My point is that, in this case, those constants matter.  These are not just arithmetic operations; they are random memory accesses, which are brutally slow on a modern system (relatively speaking).

Comment: I wouldn't have commented about it on runtime. It's just that you said there were `O(log n) "steps"` and in that case there is no difference. If you had said, for example `2 log n steps`, I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: @quasiverse:  Good point.  The way I wrote it made it sound like I don't know that changing bases on a logarithm is just a constant factor.  I have changed my wording.  Thanks.